# Missing back button after changing to the new materin theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

After changing from the Holo theme to the new material theme (Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar), all the back buttons in my action bar in gone.

This is my app which should have a back button:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.LeagueActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_league"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.LeagueListActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.LeagueListActivity" />

</activity>
```

And my app theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- App core design -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/greenDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Not sure why. Did you fix it?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution for that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in your activity's onCreate where it needs a back/up to parent button.

This fixed it for me.